# Помогите объединить регулярку php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярка

```
    $pattern = '~
    https?://         # Required scheme. Either http or https.
    (?:[0-9A-Z-]+\.)? # Optional subdomain.
    (?:               # Group host alternatives.
      youtu\.be/      # Either youtu.be,
    | youtube         # or youtube.com or
      (?:-nocookie)?  # youtube-nocookie.com
      \.com           # followed by
      \S*             # Allow anything up to VIDEO_ID,
      [^\w\s-]       # but char before ID is non-ID char.
    )                 # End host alternatives.
    ([\w-]{11})      # $1: VIDEO_ID is exactly 11 chars.
    (?=[^\w-]|$)     # Assert next char is non-ID or EOS.
    (?!               # Assert URL is not pre-linked.
      [?=&+%\w.-]*    # Allow URL (query) remainder.
      (?:             # Group pre-linked alternatives.
        [\'"][^<>]*>  # Either inside a start tag,
      | </a>          # or inside <a> element text contents.
      )               # End recognized pre-linked alts.
    )                 # End negative lookahead assertion.
    [?=&+%\w.-]*        # Consume any URL (query) remainder.
    ~ix';
```

Которая парсит ссылки youtube, нужно вытащить еще параметр времени,

```
(t=((\d+h)?(\d+m)?(\d+s)?))
```

Сложная конструкция, помогите разобраться

Comment: покажите пример ссылки со временим

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy73FP65dNA&t=4h8m18s

Comment: вы слышали про `parse_url()`?

Comment: Хотя нет, рано радуюсь, у меня ссылка в тексте и ссылки, если посмотрите ругулярку могут быть разными

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
/https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)?youtu(?:be(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/.*v=|\.be\/)([-\w]{11})(?:.*[\?&#](star)?t=([\dhms]+))?/i
```

Для текста

```
https://ru.youtube.com/watch?v=Xy73FP65dNA&t=4h8m18s
https://youtu.be/_uspf71JkjI?list=UU7JOTODmlIFJc8u_3BTrXZw
http://youtu.be/U5rQrH3z4Ug?t=27m35s
https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/watch?v=EgqUJOudrcM?t=3m28s
```

выводит результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тест https://regex101.com/r/aK0kV7/1

**UPD** Чуть исправил, чтобы вместо 3 элемента время выдавалось во втором

```
/https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)?youtu(?:be(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/.*v=|\.be\/)([-\w]{11})(?:.*[\?&#](?:star)?t=([\dhms]+))?/i
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/aK0kV7/2