# BB-код вставки видео с ютуба

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Вот реулярка:

```
#\[video\]http(s*)://(.+?)\[/video\]#si
```

Юзеру выдаёт фрейм, где src=(адрес между тегов видео).

Всё работает, но вместо видео можно поставить любую страницу. Как в регулярке проверить наличие `youtube.com`?

Comment: Вот вам ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444149/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-php/451325#451325 Возвращает id видео и точку старта по времени, если она указана. Если такой такая регулярка подойдет, отметьте свой вопрос как дубликат.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нормального ответа не получил, пришлось самому:

```
/\[video\]https?:\/\/(?:[a-z\d-]+\.)?youtu(?:be(?:-nocookie)?\.com\/.*v=|\.be\/)([-\w]{11})(?:.*[\?&#](?:star)?t=([\dhms]+))?\[\/video\]/i
```

Comment: Вы скопировали регулярку из моего ответа, так что ваш вопрос считаю дубликатом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444149/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-php

Comment: @Visman мне пришлось её править, так что ваш ответ лишь отдалённая подсказка

Comment: Конечно, дописали в начале `\[video\]` и в конце `\[\/video\]` - это очень сильно изменило поведение регулярного выражения :)

Comment: @Visman если я в рег не шарю, то и это нормально для меня

Answer (score 0):

Можно перед регулярным выражением вставить условие поиска в ссылке, что-то вот на подобии такого. [Strripos() - оф. документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strripos.php)

Comment: нужно именно регулякой, не думаю что это сложно

Comment: @Rammsteinik я думаю тогда Вам надо ознакомиться с данной статьёй в вики: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F      там есть раздел "Просмотр вперёд и назад"

Comment: Шаблонные ответы мне не нужны, не понимаю регулярки.